# C# - Entity Framework code-first - map object into two tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, mapping, code-first

Assuming I have data model defined like this:

```
class Geometry
{
   public ICollection<Point> Points { get; set; }
}

class Point
{
   public int X { get; set; }
   public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map it into the following database tables:

```
GeometriesTable
-- [GeometryId] int, key
-- [GeometryData] <-- a BLOB here!!!

PointsTable
-- [PointId] int, key
-- [GeometryId] int, foreign key
-- [X] int
-- [Y] int
```

My `[GeometryData]` BLOB basically consists of Points IDs that make up the geometry and a couple of additional meta-information.

Taking the meta stuff away, those BLOBs would look like this:

```
[ N (points count) - 4 bytes ]
[ Points[0].Id     - 4 bytes ] 
[ Points[1].Id     - 4 bytes ] 
[ Points[2].Id     - 4 bytes ] 
... 
[ Points[N-1].Id   - 4 bytes ]
```

(that is (N+1)*4 bytes for each BLOB.)

BLOB is used (instead of a simple one-to-many relation) for a couple of performance reasons. That is something that can not be changed.

I created the following entities to project the model:

```
class GeometryEntity
{
   [Key]
   [Column("GeometryId")]
   public int Id { get; set; } 

   [Column("GeometryData")]
   public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

class PointEntity
{
   [Key]
   [Column("PointId")]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Column("GeometryId")]
   public int GeometryId { get; set; }

   [Column("X")]
   public int X { get; set; }

   [Column("Y")]
   public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Now, provided I have some `IEnumerable<Geometry>` I would like to be able to populate the tables (a `DbSet<GeometryEntity>` and a `DbSet<PointEntity>`). The particular problem is that I don't know how to assign points IDs from the `PointsTable` to the corresponding points IDs in my geometry BLOBs.

Any ideas how a mapping like this could be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, provided I have some `IEnumerable<Geometry>` I would like to be
>   able to populate the tables (a `DbSet<GeometryEntity>` and a
>   `DbSet<PointEntity>`).

Ok, let's define

```
IEnumerable<Geometry> ProvidedGeometries =
    new Geometry[]
    {
        new Geometry()
        {
            Points = new PointEntity[]
    {
        new PointEntity() { GeometryId=1, X=1, Y=1, Id = 1},
        new PointEntity() { GeometryId=1, X=1, Y=2, Id = 2},
        new PointEntity() { GeometryId=1, X=2, Y=1, Id = 3},
        new PointEntity() { GeometryId=1, X=2, Y=2, Id = 4}
    }
        },
    new Geometry()
        {
            Points = new PointEntity[]
    {
        new PointEntity() { GeometryId=2, X=1, Y=1, Id = 5},
        new PointEntity() { GeometryId=2, X=1, Y=2, Id = 6}
    }
        }
    };
```

I think you can populate the tables using the `Configuration.Seed`.

with the following pseudo code

```
protected override void Seed(YourContext context)
{
    context.GeometryEntities.AddOrUpdate(
        // see the following Linq part
        );

    context.PointEntities.AddOrUpdate(
        // see the following Linq part
        );
}
```

or by a standard update with `SaveChanges`

```
using (var ctx = new YourContext())
{
   ctx.PointEntities.AddRange(Points);       //see below
   ctx.GeometryEntites.AddRange(Geometries); // " "
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

> The particular problem is that I don't know how to assign points IDs
>   from the `PointsTable` to the corresponding points IDs in my geometry
>   BLOBs.

Besides the *specific* EF *implementation* of your `context`, I think that the following code could give you an idea of the Linq part.

```
IEnumerable<PointEntity> Points =ProvidedGeometries
                    .SelectMany(g => g.Points);


var geometries = Points.GroupBy(
    p => p.GeometryId,
    p => BitConverter.GetBytes(p.Id),
    (id, points) =>
    new GeometryEntity()
    {
        Id = id,
        Data = 
        BitConverter.GetBytes(points.Count()).Concat(
            points.Aggregate( (a,b) => a.Concat(b).ToArray() )
        ).ToArray()
    }
    );
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *specific EF implementation*? I am quite new to EF itself and would really appreciate a piece of advice

Comment: @bashis Ok, received: I'll try to expand this answer, adding the EF context

Comment: I guess you have to override the Configuration.Seed to populate the tables and I've added a pointer to your provided geometries as a starting point in my edit.